# Visual Studio Core Features - ENU Fatal error during installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

## ENU Fatal error during installation

[visual studio 2013 Professional installation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJjsF.png)
When I am going to install Visual Studio 2013 Professional I am facing this problem. Installer says that " Visual Studio Core Features - ENU Fatal error during installation ".

I have tried several times after restarting my PC. But, same thing happens.

I had visual studio 2013 Pro & Community 2015 in this PC. I just uninstalled these. But, when I am going to reinstall this I am facing that problem. I am totally feed up. No solution found any where. But this is a common problem as I have searched everywhere.

What the solution. Please, give me suggestions!

Log shows:

[1CE8:2320][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1CE8:2320][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[10E8:1D60][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with other full download and the web installer from time to time. Using the other one can help.

I.e. if the web install fails I use the full install.

Also ensure you are all up to date, had issues with certificates before and a update fixed this.

There are logs the installer creates may give you more info. Do a search to find out where.

Comment: [1CE8:2320][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.

[1CE8:2320][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

[10E8:1D60][2016-07-28T00:57:13]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.